# How do I transform glOrtho clipping planes?

Tags: c, opengl, geometry, opentk, clipping

I've created an OpenGL application where I define a viewing volume with glOrtho(). Then I use gluLookAt() to transform all the points. 
The problem is - as soon as I do this all the points fall out of the clipping plane because it is "left behind". And I end up with a black screen.

How do I change the viewing volume so that it is still tight to my objects once they have been transformed by gluLookAt()?

Here's some code to help better illustrate my problem:

```
Vector3d eyePos = new Vector3d(0.25, 0.25, 0.6);
Vector3d point = new Vector3d(0, 0, 0.001);            
Vector3d up = new Vector3d(0, 1,0);            
Matrix4d mat = Matrix4d.LookAt(eyePos, point, up);

GL.Viewport(0, 0, glControl1.Width, glControl1.Height);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
GL.LoadIdentity();  
GL.Ortho(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);

GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
GL.LoadIdentity();  

GL.LoadMatrix(ref mat);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.DepthMask(true);
GL.ClearDepth(1.0);
GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Triangles);
GL.Vertex3(0.2, 0.3, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0, 0.600, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0.600, 0.600, 0.01);
GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
GL.Vertex3(0, 0.6, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0.2, 0.3, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0.7, 0.5, 0.03);
GL.Color3(Color.Red);
GL.Vertex3(0.100, 0.000, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0, 0.0, 0.01);
GL.Vertex3(0.600, 0.600, 0.03);

GL.End();
glControl1.SwapBuffers();
```

I suppose a more succinct revision of my question is how do I transform two points by the lookat matrix?("mat" in my code)

Comment: Looks like you need to change camera position (glLookAt). Maybe we can attach images to better understund what you want.

Comment: @Unick - I've added the code I'm using, the coordinates I'm using work fine if I don't load the lookat matrix. Once the lookat matrix is loaded the culling planes don't change with the rest of the coordinates and they all fall out of the cull.

Comment: Ca you post the line of code, where you set the ModelViewMatrix with the gluLookAt() function? What your are doing with your orthographic projection is to draw everything a cube in the upper right corner of the camera position with the dimension of 1 along the viewing direction.

Comment: Oh, wait a moment. I just saw the line at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got your problem.

You set the camera position to (0.25, 0.25, 0.6) and with the point to look at your view direction is (-0.25, -0.25, -0.599) (has to be normalised). As I mentioned in my comment below your question, you are drawing a cube in the upper right corner of your view direction.
So the two points (0.25, 0.25, 0.6) (the camera position) and the point defined by the camera position and your view direction, your up vector and your right vector (Have a look at [this](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/images/Graphics3D_Orthographic.png)) define the cube of the things which are shown on the screen (the two points define a diagonal within the cube). Unfortunatly, all of your points are not within this cube.

May it be, that you mixed up the camera position with the point you wanna look at? The change of the two values should solve your problem. The rest of your code seems to be correct. The only thing you have to do is to check whether your points are within the clip space of your projections. Another solution to check where your points are, would be to use, e.g. the keyboard input, to move your camera dynamically.

Comment: The points fall within the viewing volume if I load the lookat matrix before I alter the projection matrix. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I don't know the standard value of the projection matrix either. A possibility to have a better look on this is to install blender and create a scene with this parameters. You may find the answer there.  On monday, I could tell you more, if you need more help.

Comment: There may be another error caused by setting the near plane to `0`. This can cause a division by zero error and could cause your problem. But usually this should just happen with a perspective projection. Try setting it to `0.01` or something similar, to avoid this problem.